# sklearn SVM, different accuracy in Python2 vs Python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scikit-learn, svm

I have the following code where I am doing 4 fold cross-validation on a dataset with **feature vector** size **11156** and **129** **data points**.

But the issue is that the **same** code gives **different results** when I run it using **Python2** compiler vs when I run it using the **Python3** compiler.

In the case of **Python2** it gives accuracy values in the **90s** while in case of **Python3** it gives accuracy values in **70s** and **80s**

```
from __future__ import division
import scipy.io as sio
import numpy as np
from sklearn import svm
import random
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix as cm
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# Loading Data
data = sio.loadmat('data.mat')

feat_highcurve_u = np.array(data['HiCurve'])[0]
feat_lowcurve_u = np.array(data['LoCurve'])[0]

feat_highcurve = np.array([np.array(x[0]
                [int(len(x[0])/2) - 2789:
                 int(len(x[0])/2) + 2789]) 
                for x in feat_highcurve_u])
feat_lowcurve = np.array([np.array(x[0]
                [int(len(x[0])/2) - 2789:
                 int(len(x[0])/2) + 2789])
                for x in feat_lowcurve_u])

X_data = [np.concatenate((a,b), axis = 0) 
          for a,b in zip(feat_highcurve, 
                         feat_lowcurve)]

X = np.array(X_data)
X = np.transpose(X,(1,0))
avg_X = np.array([sum(x)/len(x) 
                  for x in X])

X_data = [x-avg_X for x in X_data]

y_labels = data['ClassLabels']
y_labels = np.array([(x[0]-1) 
                     for x in y_labels])


def calculate_ber(c_mat):
    val = 0
    for index, row in enumerate(c_mat):
        val += (np.sum(row) - row[index])/ np.sum(row)

    return val / len(c_mat)


def apply_svm(nu=0.1, kernel='rbf', degree=3):
    clf = svm.NuSVC(random_state=0, nu=nu, kernel=kernel, degree=degree)

    avg_accuracy = 0
    avg_ber = 0

    for n in range(10):
        # Randomizing the data
        combined = list(zip(X_data, y_labels))
        random.shuffle(combined)
        X_data[:], y_labels[:] = zip(*combined)

        # Splitting into 4 folds
        X_folds = [X_data[i:i+int(len(X_data)/4)] for i in range(0, len(X_data), int(len(X_data)/4))]
        y_folds = [y_labels[i:i+int(len(y_labels)/4)] for i in range(0, len(y_labels), int(len(y_labels)/4))]

        if(len(X_folds) == 5):
            X_folds[3] = np.concatenate((X_folds[3], X_folds[4]), axis = 0)
            X_folds.pop()

            y_folds[3] = np.concatenate((y_folds[3], y_folds[4]), axis = 0)
            y_folds.pop()

        accuracy = 0
        ber = 0

        # Iterating over folds
        for i in range(4):
            # Selecting test fold
            X_test = X_folds[i]
            y_test = y_folds[i]

            # Concatenating the rest of the folds
            o = [i for i in range(4)]
            o.remove(i)

            X_train = np.concatenate((X_folds[o[0]], X_folds[o[1]], X_folds[o[2]]), axis = 0)
            y_train = np.concatenate((y_folds[o[0]], y_folds[o[1]], y_folds[o[2]]), axis = 0)

            # Training SVM to fit the data
            clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

            # Testing the SVM
            preds = clf.predict(X_test)
            accuracy += (len([i for i in range(len(preds)) if preds[i] == y_test[i]])/len(preds))
            c_mat = cm(y_test, preds)
            ber += calculate_ber(c_mat)

        #print("Four fold cross-validation accuracy: Step("+str(n+1)+"): ",accuracy/4.0)
        avg_accuracy += (accuracy/4)
        avg_ber += (ber/4)

    print("After ten steps Average Accuracy: ", avg_accuracy/10) 
    print("After ten steps Average BER: ", avg_ber/10) 
    return ((avg_accuracy/10), (avg_ber/10))

nu_accuracies = {}
nu_values = [0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25, 0.30]

for nu_val in nu_values:
    nu_accuracies[nu_val] = apply_svm(nu=nu_val)

print("Final Metrics: ", nu_accuracies)
```

Comment: It is quite possibly an implementation detail in sklearn that is causing such a stark difference in your output.

Comment: `NuSVC` has a random_state parameter. Please set it to any same integer in both versions and then try. Also you are shuffling the data, that may be a cause of change. First try both versions with static data (no change, no cross-validation, just train all data and post `clf.score()`). Then apply fixed kfold cv, (without shuffling the data).

Comment: Tried with the same random_state parameter, still different results.

Comment: But without shuffling it gives same results on both versions. Why is that?

Comment: Because shuffling changes the training and testing data each time. And results depend on that.

Comment: But why are results different ? Because I am doing random shuffling in both Python2 and Python3.

Comment: Is Python2's shuffling different from Python3?

Comment: No. Shuffle uses random number generator which is typically seeded by the system time. So each time you run the code, shuffling will result in slightly different data (irrespective of python version).

Answer (score 0):

A late comment but for anyone else that is looking for differences in the two - sklearn changed their default solver for [logistic regression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html), this could be the difference in some cases. some of the SVM implementations have undergone other changes in default parameters.